# Does anyone have recent experience with CiviCRM for RSForm?

Tags: contacts, joomla

This Joomla plugin is supposed to provide the ability to update a civiCRM contact record based on a matching email address submitted in an RSForm submission.

Does anyone have recent experience with this plugin? Will it work with latest RSForms and civiCRM 5.21.x?

Answer (score 4):

I purchased the extension, and can confirm that it work with latest release of civiCRM.

Answer (score 2):

[CiviCRM for RSForm extension](https://civicrm.org/extensions/civicrm-for-rsform) is a [paid](https://nswd.co/extensions/paid/civicrm-for-rsform) version and is maintained by [NSWD](https://nswd.co/). The [extension page](https://nswd.co/extensions/paid/civicrm-for-rsform) does say it supports from Civi 5.1. Since its a paid version, we don't have access to its code, it would be worth asking for a [support](https://nswd.co/extensions/help-desk) from [NSWD](https://nswd.co/)